# Can I import a drupal block into a mosaico mailing template?

Tags: mailing, mosaico

I'd like to be able to pull in drupal blocks. e.g. index of latest news. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

I think this Fuzion [extension](https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/civicrm_views_token) could provide what you need. Can't say i have tested it for a long time but it used to provide that functionality as a token to include in civimail so not sure why it couldn't do same in mosaico